# MySQL falsely allowing duplicate entries when one of the fields involved is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Using InnoDB/MySQLi, I have a simple table: `mytable`. The table has four fields: `id` (primary, auto_inc), `field1`, `field2`, `field3`. All of them are `BIGINT` and, except for `id`, can be `NULL`.

I have added a unique constraint like so:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX(field1,field2,field3);
```

However, I am perfectly able to add the following rows without any error being generated. I would like for this to generate a 'duplicate' error, but it doesn't:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL,3,NULL)
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL,3,NULL)
```

It only generates a 'duplicate' error if all of the fields have non-NULL values - e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2,3,4)
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2,3,4)
```

How can I tell MySQL to generate 'duplicate' errors even if one (or more) of the fields have `NULL` values?

**EDIT:** This was previously added as a "bug" to MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25544

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare NULL's (if you compare anything with NULL even NULL=NULL the results is always `FALSE`) this behavior is documented in [MySQL ref.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

So I think the only way is define columns NOT NULL or handle this issue in a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is - in comparison of NULL-s. You should understand logical meaning of NULL. And it is "no value". Not *"zero value"* or *"unknown value"*, but *"no value"*. That's a big difference.

That is why making part of unique index NULL-able is certainly bad idea. You can not compare NULL's as you can not compare two values, both of which are absent. Thus, DBMS can not maintain NULL-s to be unique as far as comparison isn't applicable to them in normal way. Yes, such things as [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator exist in MySQL (or `IS NULL` in other DBMS) - but that is about technical resolution of how to deal with comparisons with NULL values - but not the logical.

So you're in the middle of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do not use NULL-s with unique keys - they can not be there by definition of what is NULL and what is intention of unique key. And from the [technical viewpoint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) (see part about index creation), `NULL=NULL` will always result in *false* - thus, it's permitted to insert NULL value if another NULL-value exists.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: [How to Use Unique Indexes in MySQL and Other Databases](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-unique-indexes-mysql-databases/)
and see the "MySQL NULLs" section.

Comment: If this is correct, then the answer is that it cannot be done - I simply cannot use fields that can be NULL in a unique index and avoid the problem I'm having. In the future, your contribution to the question (i.e., simply providing a link) would have been better off as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: MySQL treats NULL values in this case some like empty value which can't be compared to another value, so it won't throw any exception.

I would provide comment instead of answer, but I'm 14pts. short for that at a time ;-D

Comment: Apologies, I had forgotten that you needed a certain reputation level to add comments :)